# When to use the plural of "nature"?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage

Someone told me that the word *nature* should not be plural in my sentence. I would argue, however, that it is obvious that it requires an "s". The problematic sentence is as follow:

> We must exploit constraints of different natures (temporal, logical, etc.) [...]

If I replace the word nature by *type*, type would be plural. However, if I am correct, the word *nature* is a case similar to the word *information*. In French, I would put an *s* to the word information in this sentence:

> There is a lot of information to process

Can someone help me clarify this? Is there a simple and general rule for the words like *information* and *nature*? When must they be plural?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Singletons -- things of which there are only one -- are not usually pluralized.

If you were using *nature* in the sense of "the material world, excluding human activities" there is only one, and it could not be pluralized.

However your meaning is that of a "kind, sort, or character" which certainly can be pluralized.

Comment: I think the confusion here comes because the word is being used with two different definitions.